# Wi-fi adapter not found (only the 1st boot after being logged on windows)

Tags: wireless, adapter

When I log in to Linux the first time after being logged in windows, at the Wi-Fi settings it always appears: wifi adapter not found. Then, I restart the PC and Wi-Fi always works. Since it becomes very repetitive and it is a very boring method, I would like to know the cause of this problem and possible solutions for it.

My pc is an Asus laptop x571gt and the Ubuntu version I'm using is 18.04.4 LTS.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
    00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
    00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a368] (rev 10)
    0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
    1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
    2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `uname -a; dkms status`

```
    Linux pedro-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X571GT-X571GT 5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 04:17:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/*; dmesg | grep iwl`

```
    /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
    /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
    /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
    /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
    /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:remove iwlwifi \
    /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf:(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
    [   14.581229] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [   14.765885] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
    [   14.765888] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
    [   14.766273] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
    [   15.328227] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
    [   15.336978] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
    [   15.337426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
    [   15.385841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 24:ee:9a:e8:fc:92
    [   15.454703] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
    [   17.985575] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
    [   34.480876] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
    [   34.598790] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
    [   34.665242] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
    [   34.681305] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. Preferably after first boot when Wi-Fi is not working.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a little confused. Why should I edit my question? I'm new here, sorry!

Comment: In order to get an answer, you need to provide some more information. Editing your quesition is the right way to do it.

Comment: Please also add output of `uname -a; dkms status`.

Comment: The last one `grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/*; dmesg | grep iwl`. Pleas format the text properly yourself this time. https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14089/please-can-people-format-code-properly

Comment: All looks good to me. I have no ideas. One idea. You don't shutdown Windws properly. There is a feature "Fast Boot" that may be a problem. Windows hibernates instead of shutting down.

Comment: To change that I should go into the BIOS, right?

Comment: No, it is a Windows setting.

Comment: like this https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! Should I now answer my own question?

Comment: I can write it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Windows Fast Startup feature.

When you shutdown Windows, it doesn't really shuts down, but hibernates.

It may cause trouble for dual boot systems including wireless hardware and access to NTFS Windows partitions.

It is recommended to disable this feature in Windows settings.